# Redirect subdomain on tripod

Tags: 301-redirect

I have an old subdomain on tripod which I'd like to redirect (301) to my new domain. They don't seem to offer redirection for subdomain even with a subscription.

Has anyone had any luck permanently (301) redirecting a subdomain on tripod to a new domain?

Should I do a "link rel canonical" to point to the new site together with a meta refresh redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google treats a meta refresh set a 0 seconds just like a 301.

Comment: mod_asis can be used for 301 redirects on tripod http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_asis.html

Comment: By the way , canonical won't work across domains ie. won't work with tripod.

Comment: Actually, google supports cross canonical: http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/12/handling-legitimate-cross-domain.html